# How to create a relation for User, groups & groups metaData using TypeORM?

Tags: mysql, relational-database, nestjs, typeorm

Creating the MySQL Table relationships, and confused to implement which Relationship should be implemented on User -> Groups -> GroupsMetaData.

User.id = OneToMany  (Groups)

Groups = ManyToOne (Users)

Groups.id = ManyToMany (GroupsMetaData)

GroupsMetaData = ManyToOne(Groups)

Using TypeORM for implementing this approach.

**Users.entity.ts**

```
  @OneToMany(type => Groups, groups => groups.uid)
  groups:Groups[]
```

**Groups.entity.ts**

```
  @ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.groups)
  uid:User
```

Stucked to create the relations for Groups and GroupsMetaData.

Thanks

**It's not a professional way for an explanation, I tried for the best explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**User entity**

```
@OneToMany(type => Groups, groups => groups.uid)
groups:Groups[]
```

**Group Entity**

```
@ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.groups)
user: User

@ManyToOne(type => GroupMetadata, gmeta => gmeta.groups)
details: GroupMetadata
```

**GroupMetadata Entity**

```
@OneToMany(type => Groups, groups => groups.uid)
groups: Groups[]
```

With that config you'll have something like this:
[image: SQL diagram]

A many to many relation between user and groupmetadata using group as junction table. I recommend you to change the name of some tables, group could be called "user_group" and group metadata can be renamed as group.

Let me know if this answers your question

Comment: Error: Entity metadata for User#groups was not found. Check if you specified a correct entity object and if it's connected in the connection options.

Comment: Show me your typeorm config file, that error means that you're not importing the entity on the config